# Usage of "having"

Tags: word-usage, gerunds

I'm confused whether it is okay to use "having" in this sentence.

> *Imagine ***having*** everything you need in one place.*

If it isn't, please suggest a better one.

Comment: It's OK. Why do you think it isn't?

Answer (score 2):

> Imagine having everything you need in one place.

The above sentence is correctly using the present participle of "have" (having)